# Book about a crippled man fighting the devil

Tags: story-identification

I read a book about 10 years ago where one of the protagonists is a sort of Knight, sent on a mission against the devil from a lady. 
This man has nightmares that show him the future: if he is doing well on his mission he sees peace, when he fails he sees a world ruled by the devil. 
He is not the only warrior that the lady knighted. Another one is a native American.

The other protagonist is a girl which doesn't know is the daughter of the devil. He is coming to take her to make her ruler of the world. She has a sort of wolf that protects her and an elf helper.

I know the book is part of a series but I only read this one. The author was someone famous in this genre but can't remember the name.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118334/girl-with-magic-confronts-a-demon-and-heals-tree

Comment: @Otis The other question mentions different details

Comment: I don't think that's a duplicate: the answer may be the same but the details in the question are completely different.

Comment: @Moriarty, algiogia, story ID questions are closed on the basis of duplicate answers, not duplicate questions. This creates links between questions with different details and helps provide more chance of confirmation for future searchers. It's not intended to convey anything negative.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Terry Brooks: "Running With The Demon".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_with_the_Demon

Here's your crippled Knight, Lady and native American Knight:

> John is a "Knight of the Word", charged with helping preserve the balance between the Word (the representation of goodness and light in the world) and the Void (the summation of evil and darkness). After his post-graduate work, John traveled to Wales and happened upon a glade called Fairy Glen in the country around Betws-y-Coed. He is met by the Lady (the voice of the Word) and learns that he is the descendant of Owain Glyndŵr, a great Welsh "patriot and warrior" who served the Word. John was then charged by the Lady to embrace the Word and fight against the Void whenever he is called on. After returning to America, he is visited by a Native American named O'olish Amaneh, who reminds him of his oath and hands him a rune-engraved staff of great magic. Upon taking the staff, John's leg is crippled as a reminder that he is dependent upon the staff, and through it, the Word.

The other protaganist, with her wolf protector and elf helper:

> Nest Freemark is a fourteen-year-old girl of Hopewell, Illinois, who has inherited magical powers from her mother's lineage... She is aided in this task by a six-inch tree-like sylvan named Pick, an insightful barn owl named Daniel, and an ethereal wolfen creature named Wraith,

Comment: Got there just before I did.

Comment: Yeah, a famous author like Brooks was always going to go quickly.

Answer (score 8):

I wonder if this could be [Knight of the Word](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Knight_of_the_Word) by Terry Brooks sequel to Running with the Demon, which is now regarded as a precursor to his Shannara series.
John Ross is a Knight of the Word one of a handful of individuals that are attempting to keep the world from becoming overrun by Demons.

He has recently failed to protect a group of school children and is trying to recover from his injuries and plagued with guilt. He is haunted by visions of what the world will become if he and his fellow Knights fail.

The female character sounds like Nest Freemark, a teenage girl who also is a Knight, she is aided by Pick called a slyvan in the book who would seem elf like, and a spirit wolf creature called Wraith.
Her real father is a powerful demon, though not actually the devil in the Christian sense.

There is an Indian character called O'olish Ameneh last of his tribe the Sinnissippi, he is not a Knight of the Word but has powerful shamanistic magic.